# Running play on cloudbees - evolution error

Tags: playframework, cloudbees

When I deploy my app, I am seeing this error:

```
[[33mwarn[0m] play - Run with -DapplyEvolutions.default=true if you want to run them automatically (be careful) 
Oops, cannot start the server. 
@6g6lgcebe: Database 'default' needs evolution! 
at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Evolutions.scala:484) 
at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.withLock(Evolutions.scala:507) 
at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:461) 
at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:459) 
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
```

How do I run these evolutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest answer is to set applyEvolutions.default=true - in your application.conf - this isn't always recommended but it if you want to have your evolutions always automatically applied when they need to be - that option will do it for you.

see https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Playframework#HDatabaseEvolutions for more info.